# Parallelizing array row similarity calculations in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a large-ish array `artist_topic_probs` (112,312 item rows by ~100 feature columns), and I want to calculate the pairwise cosine similarity between a (large sample) of random pairs of rows from this array. Here's the relevant bits of my current code

```
# the number of random pairs to check (10 million here)
random_sample_size=10000000

# I want to make sure they're unique, and that I'm never comparing a row to itself
# so I generate my set of comparisons like so:
np.random.seed(99)
comps = set()
while len(comps)<random_sample_size:
    a = np.random.randint(0,112312)
    b= np.random.randint(0,112312)
    if a!=b:
        comp = tuple(sorted([a,b]))
        comps.add(comp)
# convert to list at the end to ensure sort order 
# not positive if this is needed...I've seen conflicting opinions
comps = list(sorted(comps))
```

This generates a list of tuples, where each are the two rows between which I'll calculate similarity. Then I just use a simple loop to calculate all the similarities:

```
c_dists = []
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
for a,b in comps:
    c_dists.append(cosine(artist_topic_probs[a],artist_topic_probs[b]))
```

(of course, `cosine` here gives *distance*, not a *similarity*, but we can easily get that with `sim = 1.0 - dist`. I used similarity in the title because it's the more common term)

This works fine, but isn't too fast, and I need to repeat the procedure many times. I have 32 cores to work with, so parallelization seems like a good bet, but I'm not sure the best way to go about it. My idea was something like:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=32)
c_dists = [pool.apply(cosine, args=(artist_topic_probs[a],artist_topic_probs[b])) 
    for a,b in comps]
```

But testing this approach out on my laptop with some test data hasn't been working (it just hangs, or at least is taking so much longer than the simple loop that I got sick of waiting and killed it). My concern is the indexing of the matrix being some sort of bottleneck, but I'm not sure. Any ideas on how to effectively parallelize this (or otherwise speed up the process)?

Comment: Suggestion use [Apache Spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark)

Comment: Im not sure that this problem space is a good candidate for parallelisation ...  at least not the way you currently have it described ...

Comment: I've considered this, but it seems like a big hammer for a relatively simple problem. But I guess the general approach would be to broadcast the array to all the executors, then just do a simple map on an RDD of the tuples to be compared? I.e. (assuming `comps` is now an RDD) `arr = sc.broadcast(artist_topic_probs); c_dists = comps.map(lambda x: cosine(artist_topic_probs.value[x[0]],artist_topic_probs.value[x[1]]).collect()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you might want to use `itertools.combinations` and `random.sample` to get unique pairs in the future, but it won't work in this case due to memory issues. Then, multiprocessing is not multithreading, i.e. spawning a new process involves huge system overhead. There is little sense in spawning a process for each individual task. A task must be well worth the overhead to rationalise starting a new process, hence you'd better split all work into separate jobs (into as many pieces as the number of cores you want to use). Then, don't forget that `multiprocessing` implementation serialises the entire namespace and loads it into memory N times, where N is the number of processes. This can lead to intensive swapping if you don't have enough RAM to store N copies of your huge array. So you might want to reduce the number of cores.

**Updated** to restore initial order as you requested.

I made a test data-set of identical vectors, hence `cosine` must return a vector of zeros.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import math
import multiprocessing as mp
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
from operator import itemgetter
import itertools


def worker(enumerated_comps):
    return [(ind, cosine(artist_topic_probs[a], artist_topic_probs[b])) for ind, (a, b) in enumerated_comps]


def slice_iterable(iterable, chunk):
    """
    Slices an iterable into chunks of size n
    :param chunk: the number of items per slice
    :type chunk: int
    :type iterable: collections.Iterable
    :rtype: collections.Generator
    """
    _it = iter(iterable)
    return itertools.takewhile(
        bool, (tuple(itertools.islice(_it, chunk)) for _ in itertools.count(0))
    )


# Test data
artist_topic_probs = [range(10) for _ in xrange(10)]
comps = tuple(enumerate([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]))

n_cores = 2
chunksize = int(math.ceil(len(comps)/n_cores))
jobs = tuple(slice_iterable(comps, chunksize))

pool = mp.Pool(processes=n_cores)
work_res = pool.map_async(worker, jobs)
c_dists = map(itemgetter(1), sorted(itertools.chain(*work_res.get())))
print(c_dists)
```

Output:

```
[2.2204460492503131e-16, 2.2204460492503131e-16, 2.2204460492503131e-16, 2.2204460492503131e-16]
```

These values are fairly close to zero.

P.S.

From the `multiprocessing.Pool.apply` docs

> Equivalent of the `apply()` built-in function. It **blocks until the
>   result is ready**, so `apply_async()` is better suited for performing 
>   work in parallel. Additionally, func is only executed in one of the
>   workers of the pool.

Comment: I may be misremembering, but doesn't async not maintain order? For my purposes, order is important (because I repeat the procedure multiple times and need to compare ordered results).

Comment: @moustachio sorry, seems like I missed that requirement. Anyway, I updated the code to restore initial order.

Comment: Trying to run this now, but running into some confusion. IS your reference to `pairs` supposed to be comps?, and where is `jobs` defined?

Comment: @moustachio sorry, I forgot to cleanup after an edit. It should be okay now. In case `multiprocessing` fails to serialise the `worker` function, try `pathos.multiprocessing` instead (it's generally a lot more versatile than standard `multiprocessing`). It has absolutely identical interfaces, so you can simply `import pathos.multiprocessing as mp`)

Comment: Hmmm, still getting an error from the map: `TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not MapResult`. Trying to debug, but I'm super new to using Python's multiprocessing...

Comment: @moustachio I forgot that `Pool.map_async`, unlike `Pool.map`, outputs `MapResult`, hence you need to call `MapResult.get` to get the real output. This time I performed a test and fixed another error. The solution above runs fine.

Comment: Great! Works now, and gives me a ~ 2x speed increase on my 4core laptop. I'm expecting much better on my 32 core analysis machine. Sweet!

Comment: @moustachio glad it works for you. Since you are a beginner, I should stress that this code is quite dirty in terms of style and you might want to make it look better if it's meant to be used several times.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running into memory issues and playing with the number of cores, as I run the code multiple times (loading a different `artist_topic_probs` array each time). Do you know precisely when serializing of the namespace occurs so I can minimize my memory issues? I'm thinking maybe I should generate a new pool each time, and then call `pool.terminate()`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It happens when you create the pool of workers. I might be able to help you if you tell me how much memory your array takes.

Comment: Actually, the `pool.terminate` idea is working like a charm for now, so I think I'm good. Thanks though =)

Answer (score 1):

[`scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L267), as you can see following the link, introduces a significant overhead in your computations because for each invocation it computes the norm of the two vectors that you're analyzing at each invocation, for the size of your sample
this amounts to 20 millions norms computed, if you memorize the norms of your ~100 thousand vectors in advance you can save approximately 60% of your computation time because you have a dot product, u*v, and two norm calculations, and each of these three operations is roughly equivalent in terms of operations count.

Further, you're using explicit loops, if you could put your logic inside a vectorized `numpy` operator you could trim another large slice of your computational time.

Eventually, you talk about *cosine similarity*... consider that `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` computes the *cosine distance* instead, the relationship is easy, `cs = cd - 1` but I haven't seen this in your posted code.

Comment: Ooh, that's really helpful. I wonder if that will end up making more of a difference than parallelizing (or at the very least I can combine the two methods described so far). Then again, pre-computing the norms will only really save time in cases where the same vector appears in multiple computations. Still probably useful, though.

Comment: Regarding vectorization...I thought about that, but wasn't sure of how to go about generating the necessary data structure without a loop over `comps`....

Comment: Finally, my reference to cosine similarity was just sloppy wording. I realize this function gives distance (hence use of the variable `c_dists`). But good catch. I'll edit.